# How can we create generic method with specialized implementations?

Tags: rust

I have specialised implementation for concrete type(`f64`):

```rust
struct Total {
    total: f64
}

impl AddAssign<f64> for Total {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, rhs: f64) {
        self.total += rhs;
    }
}

trait TakeForTotal {
    fn get(&self) -> f64;
}

impl<T: TakeForTotal> AddAssign<&T> for Total {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, taker: &T) {
        self.add_assign(taker.get());
    }
}
```

This is simplified code, for demonstrate my problem.
In real:

- `Total` is a `Minimum` and `Maximum`.
- `TakeForTotal` is a trait for containers, in real is traits `High` and `Low`, and exist structs that implements these traits.
- This implementation is needed for work with f64 and with containers.
- Manually fetching numeric values from containers is possible, but it's easy to make a mistake:

```rust
minimum.add(container)
maximum.add(container)
// is better than:
minimum.add(container.low)
maximum.add(container.high)
```

It's easy to confuse `high` with `low`, and is critical bug.

---

Now I want to make `Total` for all types that implement `AddAssign`, but I can't do that, becouse for

```rust
struct Total<T> {
    total: T
}
```

implementations:

```rust
impl<T: AddAssign> AddAssign<T> for Total<T>
```

and

```rust
impl<T: TakeForTotal> AddAssign<&T> for Total<T::Output> where T::Output: AddAssign
```

now is conflicting. How best to implement? Or is it impossible?

Full code:

```rust
struct Total<T> {
    total: T
}

impl<T: AddAssign> AddAssign<T> for Total<T> {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, rhs: T) {
        self.total += rhs;
    }
}

trait TakeForTotal {
    type Output;

    fn get(&self) -> Self::Output;
}

impl<T: TakeForTotal> AddAssign<&T> for Total<T::Output> where T::Output: AddAssign {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, taker: &T) {
        self.add_assign(taker.get());
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO Rust is a bit like Go language. Trying to be "too abstract" does not feel rewarding.  It is a system programming language after all and close to the metal, you just write verbatim code. So, if you describe what you really want to accomplish in the end (from what I understand you want an easy way to aggregate values in a container?), someone here might come up with a more idiomatic solution.

Comment: @BitTickler Rather than defining what the rust programming language is, I'd better say that currently not supporting partial specialization which is a frequently asked issue is currently a defect of its design.

Comment: @Alsein And its not the only one. Closures as traits has drawbacks, too. And mixing of enum and sum types is unfortunate. Sometimes those (well in my opinion) issues make simple things overly complicated. Those and the slow tool chain are what keeping me away from Rust, while I really think people should get over C already :) and the world needs something like Rust as a replacement.